# What to do with ILSpy error "This file does not contain a managed assembly"?

Tags: windows, decompilation, .net

I'm trying to decompile an unknown Win32 executable using ILSpy. However, it only answers by giving me the useless message: 
`This file does not contain a managed assembly.`

I have also tried to use other tools like *dotPeek64* and *Teleirik* without success. Virustotal tell me that it is using:

```
[+] COMCTL32.dll
[+] ComMgr.dll
[+] KERNEL32.dll
[+] MSVCP90.dll
[+] MSVCR90.dll
[+] OLEAUT32.dll
[+] SHLWAPI.dll
[+] USER32.dll
[+] mfc90.dll
```

<strike>I'm pretty sure it is made with .NET</strike>, since this XML is present in the code:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="removed"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.MFC" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="removed"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Also note that I'm using Win8 and do not have VS installed. So my questions are:

1. **What do I need to do to resolve the above error?**
2. **What am I missing if anything?**
3. **How can I check if I have those *.dll's listed?**

EDIT: I'm now thinking it was made with plain C++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a Win32 executable, .NET executables typically imports _CorExeMain from mscoree.dll. You can use an identification tool like PEiD or Detect It Easy to confirm it.

Comment: It is a Wn32 exec, but it's probably not a .NET as I first thought, but plain C++. Then what to do?

Comment: @not2qubit use appropriate tools, like IDA pro

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Because that's a $2000+ piece of software. Surely there must be some free alternatives, that is also capable of decompiling unmanaged Win32 code into C-like code.

Comment: @not2qubit 30 seconds with search: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I know of all those and more, but I explicitly need a `decompiler`. As the tools I already mentioned doesn't seem to be able to handle (decompile) anything not made with .NET, I guess I can assume they are useless for my case.

Comment: but it looks like your application is not .NET if it were then ILSpy would handle it.