# Reversing PE - which tools should beginner use?

Tags: debugging

As a beginner  i want to ask u some questions.
Well , i'm not talking about all kinds of programs... i'm just asking for PE ( executables ) for **windows** -> **(.exe)** extension
so , i don't know which tools should i use.

And what's the difference between :

**`IDA - Ollydbg - Immunity_Debugger - x64dbg`**

Thanks ^_^ ...

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to read [Dennis Yurichev's book "Reverse Engineering for beginners"](https://beginners.re/). 
The answer to your specific question about tool difference is covered in chapter 7:
IDA is a disassembler (a tool for static analysis of the code, intended to observe the code), and all the rest are debuggers (tools for dynamic analysis, intended to observe the code's behavior in action).

In general there are a lot of different tools depending on what exactly do you want to achieve:

- Disassemblers (see answers to [Is there any disassembler to rival IDA Pro?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro) )
- Decompilers (Ida Pro has decompiler inside, there is also https://retdec.com/home/ )
- Debuggers (OllyDbg, x64dbg, etc)

Comment: Plus every web page you can find on the PE format (some esoteric tidbits are quite rare). And be very confident in your assembler skills. And, for software for Windows, know enough about its APIs to be able to find what you are looking for on MSDN.