# Does IDA Freeware 8.x support plugins?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

According to the information I searched, it is not supported in IDA 7.x and before.

Has this changed in 8.x? Because now the 8.x decompiler cloud version is free, which is different from before.

refer: [Do IDA Python plugins work with IDA free or only IDA pro?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17632/42821)

Comment: I mean just refer to the documentation. NO

Comment: @sudhackar That's quite rude as a comment. While I agree that own research should have been done up front, I don't think this was a very welcoming tone. For example the comparison table [here](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/) makes no mention of plugins and it's also not listed as a limitation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Doesn't [this Q&A](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17632/245) have the answer you are looking for? Although admittedly it probably isn't the answer you _want_. [This ticket](https://github.com/yegord/snowman/issues/158) may be equally interesting.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks your reply. I've read all the easy-to-search answers or manuals, either from a few years ago, or not clearly stated. Since the 8.x decompiler is free, I came here to ask a seemingly stupid question with full of hope.

Comment: @JoeHuang just one thought. I _know_ that they don't officially provide support for the freeware version, but I suppose if you ask them nicely you could find out by sending an email to `support@` Hex-Rays ... and once you have the authoritative answer, you could answer your own question here for the benefit of others?!